# Ошибка при отправке письма на почту

Tags: php, веб-программирование

необходима помощь. Пытаюсь реализовать регистрацию на сайте. Проблема в том, что никаких ошибок при отправке нет, но письмо на почту не приходит. В чем проблема?

```
<?php

    ini_set('display_errors',1);
    error_reporting('E_ALL');

    //SETTINGS//
    $server_bot = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $password_bot = 'пасс от почты на gmail';
    $mail_bot = 'логин почты gmail';
    $name_bot = 'NO_REPLY';
    $title = 'Подтверждение регистрации на ------';
    $mess = 'Для того что-бы продолжить регистрацию, перейдите по ссылке:';
    $mess1 = 'Если эту регистрацию, делали не ВЫ. Удалите письмо.';
    //SETTINGS//

    include_once('db.php');
    include_once('inc.class.php');//Различные классы и функции для упрощения работы

    $SETTINGS = new SETTINGS();//////////////////////////////START_SETTINGS_CLASS////////////////////
    $FORM = new FORM();//////////////////////////////////////START_FORM_CLASS////////////////////////
    $AUTH = new AUTH();//////////////////////////////////////START_AUTH_CLASS////////////////////////

// Присваивание переменных из предыдущей формы
    $login = htmlspecialchars($_POST['login']);
    $password = htmlspecialchars($_POST['password']);
    $mail = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']);
    $tm = time();
    $password = md5($password);
//Закончил присваивать 

//Вычисление количества записей  в БД с принятыми Логином и Емэйлом 
    $querylogin=$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE login='".$login."'");
    $numrowlogin = $querylogin->num_rows;

    $queryemail=$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE mail='".$mail."'");
    $numrowemail = $queryemail->num_rows;
//Закончил вычислять    

//Всё для боты отправки сообщ
    $mail_class = new EMAIL($email_bot); //Создаём экземпляр класса
    $mail_class->setFromName($name_bot); //Устанавливаем имя в обратном адресеc
    $validation = md5($tm);
    $messageEmail = $mess.' <a href="http://sign.tw1.ru/activate.php?valid='.$validation.'">ссылка</a> '.$mess1;
    $mailSMTP = new SMTP_EMAIL($server_bot, $mail_bot, $password_bot, $name_bot, 25); // создаем экземпляр класса
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n"; // кодировка письма
    $headers .= "From: ".$name_bot." <".$mail_bot." >\r\n"; // от кого письмо

//Проверки на уникальность и добавление в БД
    if ($numrowlogin==0){
        if ($numrowemail==0){
            if($mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `user` (`login`, `password`, `mail`, `status`, `last_act`, `reg_date`) VALUES ('$login', '$password', '$mail', 'false', $tm, $tm)")){
                $resultEmail = $mailSMTP->send($mail, $title, $messageEmail, $headers); // отправляем письмо                    
            }
            else {
                $message = "Failed to insert data information!";
                echo ($message);
            }
        }   
        else {
            $message = "That Email already exists! Please try another one!";
            echo ($message);
        }
    }
    else {
        $message = "That Login already exists! Please try another one!";
        echo ($message);
    }
    if($resultEmail){
        include ("login-done.php");
    }
    else{
        echo ('error');
    }
?>
```

Comment: Знает кто в чем дело?

Comment: До строчки  $resultEmail = скрипт доходит?

Comment: @MAX Выскакивает 2 вида ошибок, либо такая `if (!$this->_parseServer($socket, "334")) {
    fclose($socket);
    throw new Exception('Autorization error1');
   }` Или такая `if (!$this->_parseServer($socket, "235")) {
    fclose($socket);
    throw new Exception('Autorization error3');`

Comment: Судя по сообщению какая-то ошибка авторизации.

Comment: @MAX не знаете что можно сделать?

Comment: Боюсь, что нет. Ошибка, по вашему описанию «стандартная», то есть перехватывается исключение самим скриптом. Если это smtp, то там куча подводных камней, и в первую очередь курите доки по почтовому серверу, может там нужно какие-то обязательные условия использования.

Comment: 1. Логин указываете полностью с доменом? 
2. Порт какой 587? 
3. Активировали ли вы в настройках аккаунта работу с SMTP?
4. Может есть смысл использовать уже готоый Swiftmailer?

Comment: @Ninazu 1)да 2)да 3)работаю на локальной  машине 4)не знаю что это

Comment: SwiftMailer, это библиотека для отправки писем. Которая лично меня спасает от кучи головной боли. https://swiftmailer.symfony.com/docs/sending.html

Comment: @Ninazu Почитаю, спасибо, а что касаемо текущего кода?

Comment: Касательно текущего кода, вся логика по отправке у вас в **SMTP_EMAIL** классе лежит, которого не видно =)

Comment: @Ninazu класс находится в файле, но код слишком объемный, поэтому залил на файлообменник https://dropmefiles.com/b9oBU

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79027/discussion-between-ninazu-and-midnight).